# the put method is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

when i try to update my the section name i am having this error: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
there is the form:

```
<form action="sections.update" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                                           @csrf
                                           @method('PUT')
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                               <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                                               <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">section name</label>
                                               <input class="form-control" name="section_name" id="section_name" type="text">
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                               <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">description</label>
                                               <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                                           </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="modal-footer">
                                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">confirm</button>
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                                   </div>
                                   </form>
```

and that is the update controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
   {
       $id = $request->id;

       $this->validate($request, [

           'section_name' => 'required|max:255|unique:sections,section_name,' . $id,
           'description' => 'required',
       ], [

           'section_name.required' => 'section name is required',
           'section_name.unique' => 'section_name should be unique',
           'description.required' => 'description is required',

       ]);

       $sections = sections::find($id);
       $sections->update([
           'section_name' => $request->section_name,
           'description' => $request->description,
       ]);

       session()->flash('edit', 'the section is edited successfully');
       return redirect('/sections');
   }
```

Comment: `action="'sections.update"` is invalid. Did you mean `action="{{ route('sections.update') }}"`?

Comment: when i try this i am having this error: 
Missing required parameter for [Route: sections.update] [URI: sections/{section}] [Missing parameter: section]. (View: /Users/georgesmac/Desktop/invoices/resources/views/sections/sections.blade.php

Comment: Then you need to pass the id into the route. `action="{{ route('sections.update', ['section' => $your->section_id]) }}"`

Comment: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/georgesmac/Desktop/invoices/resources/views/sections/sections.blade.php)

Comment: `sections.update` requires an ID for the route, and it looks like you're not passing it in. It looks like you're using a modal as an edit popup, so you're going to have to create the route manually and find a way to pass the ID into the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the id/parameter in your form action when using put method but u re fetching id from form , so you can pass some dummy data on it. Change the form to

```
<form action="action="{{ route('sections.update', ['section' => '1']) }}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: when i try this i am having this error Missing required parameter for [Route: sections.update] [URI: sections/{section}] [Missing parameter: section]. (View: /Users/georgesmac/Desktop/invoices/resources/views/sections/sections.blade.php)

Comment: please mention full code of sections.blade.php , and /route/web.php

Comment: its very big i cant post it here

Comment: Route::resource('sections', SectionsController::class);

Comment: this is the rout of the sections

Comment: edited the answer. look into it